# A design tool to find what the color combination will look like

Tags: css

I am not a designer. Sometimes I need to have a border line or a shade of gray on a background color.

Is there a tool where I can mention

```
background color: #343434
color: #asdfgh
```

and see a line with the given background. This will be immensely helpful to me.

Comment: I don't think #asdfgh is a cool color, it is way too white...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:
http://www.colortools.net/color_mixer.html

If you prefer a desktop tool, you can download a wide variety of image design tools and open the color palette. I would imagine there are simple color tools that are not image editors, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/) several times. After all, is about common sense too. Eg: white text is not a good option for light gray background :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the [Online Color Chart Picker](http://www.febooti.com/products/iezoom/online-help/online-color-chart-picker.html) may be useful.

You can use a colour wheel to pick a colour and displays hex values. You can also pick multiple colours to enable you to work out suitable combinations.

It also suggests smart and web-safe colours if required.

Alternatively, the [Color Wheel](http://www.allprofitallfree.com/color-wheel2.html) allows you to enter hex values and preview the result - similar to photoshop color pickers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/). The default view is the usual color block combination, but the light/dark page example buttons around bottom right pop an overlay with a mock layout that shows the various colors in lots of background/border/text combinations. Something in there probably covers the scenario you want to see and probably more.

Answer (score 0):

[Colormania](http://www.blacksunsoftware.com/colormania.html) is my vote for color picking. It can detect the color of any color on your screen along with converting values between many of the available color formats. Unfortunately, like most of the other tools mentioned here, it only shows one color at a time, so not everything you are looking for.